# Query with index incredibly slow on Sort

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database, query-optimization

I have a database table with about 3.5 million rows. The table holds contract data records, with an amount, a date, and some IDs related to other tables (VendorId, AgencyId, StateId), this is the database table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[VendorContracts]
(
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,   
    [ContractDate] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [ContractAmount] [decimal](19, 4) NULL, 
    [VendorId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [AgencyId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [StateId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,

    [CreatedBy] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [LastModifiedBy] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [LastModifiedDate] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [IsActive] [bit] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_VendorContracts] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
                WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
                      OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

I have a page on my site where the user can filter a paged grid by `VendorId` and `ContractDate`, and sort by the `ContractAmount` or `ContractDate`. This is the query that EF Core produces when sorting by `ContractAmount` for this particular vendor that has over a million records:

```
DECLARE @__vendorId_0 uniqueIdentifier = 'f39c7198-b05a-477e-b7bc-cb189c5944c0';
DECLARE @__startDate_1 datetime2 = '2017-01-01T07:00:00.0000000';
DECLARE @__endDate_2 datetime2 = '2018-01-02T06:59:59.0000000';
DECLARE @__p_3 int = 0;
DECLARE @__p_4 int = 50;

SELECT [v].[Id], [v].[AdminFee], [v].[ContractAmount], [v].[ContractDate], [v].[PONumber], [v].[PostalCode], [v].[AgencyId], [v].[StateId], [v].[VendorId]
FROM [VendorContracts] AS [v]
WHERE (([v].[VendorId] = @__vendorId_0) AND ([v].[ContractDate] >= @__startDate_1)) AND ([v].[ContractDate] <= @__endDate_2)
ORDER BY [v].[ContractAmount] ASC
OFFSET @__p_3 ROWS FETCH NEXT @__p_4 ROWS ONLY
```

When I run this, it takes 50s, whether sorting `ASC` or `DESC` or offsetting by thousands, it's always 50s.

If I look at my Execution Plan, I see that it does use my index, but the Sort Cost is what's making the query take so long

[image]

This is my index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_VendorContracts_VendorIdAndContractDate] ON [dbo].[VendorContracts]
(
    [VendorId] ASC,
    [ContractDate] DESC
)
INCLUDE([ContractAmount],[AdminFee],[PONumber],[PostalCode],[AgencyId],[StateId]) 
WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF)
```

The strange thing is that I have a similar index for sorting by `ContractDate`, and that one returns results in less than a second, even on the vendor that has millions of records.

Is there something wrong with my index? Or is sorting by a `decimal` data type just incredibly intensive?

Comment: I believe you may have included the index for the date column but not the one for the amount column. Or, are you saying that the amount is only referenced as an include by that index?

Comment: Looks like a sort spill. What exactly does the warning say? It will only request memory to sort the estimated 6.6k rows but actually sorts 475k rows

Comment: So the query is using `ORDER BY [v].[ContractAmount] ASC` ... but the index does not have `ContractAmount` in its index keys? Include columns are not part of the index keys, so it has to manually sort the intermediate result set in memory.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning the only way an index would support the sort would be if the OP was to abandon the secondary seek on ContractDate and just settle for an equality seek on VendorId and residual predicate. As it currently stands the Seek will return the exact rows for the Vendor in the date range but adding a third key column wouldn't allow the sort to be avoided as the tertiary sorting would only apply for rows with the same VendorId,ContractDate values

Comment: @MartinSmith - I think you're right about the sort spill, the warning says "Operator used tempdb to spill data during execution with spill level 1 and 1 spilled thread(s), Sort wrote 10299 pages to and read 10299 pages from tempdb with granted memory 67088KB and used memory 67088KB"

Here is the warning in xml:
`<Warnings><SpillToTempDb SpillLevel="1" SpilledThreadCount="1" /><SortSpillDetails GrantedMemoryKb="67088" UsedMemoryKb="67088" WritesToTempDb="10299" ReadsFromTempDb="10299" /></Warnings>`

Would any other info be helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an index that allows the

```
VendorId = @__vendorId_0 and ContractDate BETWEEN @__startDate_1 AND @__endDate_2
```

predicate to be seeked exactly.

[image]

SQL Server estimates that 6,657 rows will match this predicate and need to be sorted so it requests a memory grant suitable for that amount of rows.

In reality for the parameter values where you see the problem nearly half a million are sorted and the memory grant is insufficient and the sort spills to disc.

50 seconds for 10,299 spilled pages does still sound unexpectedly slow but I assume you may well be on some very low SKU in Azure SQL Database?

Some possible solutions to resolve the issue might be to

1. Force it to use an execution plan that is compiled for parameter values with your largest vendor and wide date range (e.g. with `OPTIMIZE FOR` hint). This will mean an excessive memory grant for smaller vendors though which may mean other queries have to incur memory grant waits.
2. Use `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` so every invocation is recompiled for the specific parameter values passed. This means in theory every execution will get an appropriate memory grant at the cost of more time spent in compilation.
3. Remove the need for a sort at all. If you have an index on `VendorId, ContractAmount INCLUDE (ContractDate)` then the `VendorId = @__vendorId_0` part can be seeked and the index read in `ContractAmount` order. Once 50 rows have been found that match the `ContractDate BETWEEN @__startDate_1 AND @__endDate_2` predicate then query execution can stop. SQL Server might not choose this execution plan without hints though.

I'm not sure how easy or otherwise it is to apply query hints through EF but you could look at forcing a plan via query store if you manage to get the desired plan to appear there.

Comment: Yep that was exactly it, I was on the lowest tier in Azure, I moved it up and it's working great now.